# symfony2 form with self-referencing multiple checkboxes aren't presented checked in twig

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox, doctrine-orm, self-reference

Im trying to build a form with `$this->createFormBuilder` that based on a preselected supervisor supposed to show me the "vendedores' that he supervised and the others the are created but without supervisors assigned.

My queries created with query_builder works well because shows the correct data but for those that the supervisor "supervised" shows the correct data but with the checkboxes unchecked.

This is my form where "asignados" bring every user that is related to the preselected supervisor and "no_asignados" brings  every user that is without supervisor assigned.

```
$data = array();
        $formulario = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('asignados', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PDBundle:Usuario',
                //'property' => 'nombre',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($supervisorId) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.estado = :activo')
                        ->andWhere('u.tipoUsuario LIKE :vendedor')
                        ->andWhere('u.supervisor = :supervisorId')
                        ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('activo','ACTIVO')
                        ->setParameter('vendedor', 'VENDEDOR%')
                        ->setParameter('supervisorId', $supervisorId);
                }
            ))
            ->add('no_asignados', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PDBundle:Usuario',
                //'property' => 'nombre',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.tipoUsuario like :vendedor')
                        ->andWhere('u.supervisor is NULL')
                        ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('vendedor', 'VENDEDOR%');
                }
            ))
            ->add('guardar', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar','attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary',)))
            ->add('no_guardar', 'submit', array('label' => 'No guardar','attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-danger',)))
            ->getForm();
```

This my usuario.php entity

```
    <?php

    namespace PD\AppBundle\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;

    /**
     * Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PD\AppBundle\Entity\UsuarioRepository")
     * 
     */
    class Usuario implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * Método requerido por la interfaz UserInterface
         */
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
        }

        /**
         * Método requerido por la interfaz UserInterface
         */
        public function getRoles()
        {
            return array('ROLE_USUARIO');
        }

        /**
         * Método requerido por la interfaz UserInterface
         */
        //public function getUsername()
        //{
        //    return $this->getEmail();
        //}

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=100)
         * @GRID\Column(title="Nombre")
         */
        private $nombre;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="apellidos", type="string", length=100)
         * @GRID\Column(title="Apellidos")
         */
        private $apellidos;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=100)
         */
        private $username;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=100)
         */
        private $password;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=100)
         */
        private $salt;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100)
         * @GRID\Column(title="Correo")
         */
        private $email; 

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="direccion", type="text")
         */
        private $direccion;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="fecha_alta", type="datetime")
         */
        private $fechaAlta;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="fecha_nacimiento", type="datetime")
         */
        private $fechaNacimiento;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="dui", type="string", length=9)
         */
        private $dui;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="tipo_usuario", type="string", length=25)
         * @GRID\Column(title="Rol")
         */
        private $tipoUsuario;

        /**
         * @var boolean
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="estado", type="string", length=20)
         */
        private $estado;

/** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario", inversedBy="supervisados") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Type(type="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario")
     * @GRID\Column(field="supervisor.nombre", title="Nombre supervisor")
     * @GRID\Column(field="supervisor.apellidos", title="Apellido supervisor")
     */
    protected $supervisor;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario", mappedBy="supervisor", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        protected $supervisados;


        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->fechaAlta = new \DateTime();
            $this->supervisados = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        public function getNombreApellidos(){
            return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos();
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set nombre
         *
         * @param string $nombre
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setNombre($nombre)
        {
            $this->nombre = $nombre;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get nombre
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getNombre()
        {
            return $this->nombre;
        }

        /**
         * Set password
         *
         * @param string $password
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get password
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        /**
         * Set salt
         *
         * @param string $salt
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setSalt($salt)
        {
            $this->salt = $salt;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get salt
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getSalt()
        {
            return $this->salt;
        }

        /**
         * Set direccion
         *
         * @param string $direccion
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setDireccion($direccion)
        {
            $this->direccion = $direccion;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get direccion
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDireccion()
        {
            return $this->direccion;
        }

        /**
         * Set username
         *
         * @param string $username
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setUsername($username)
        {
            $this->username = $username;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get username
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }

        /**
         * Set fechaAlta
         *
         * @param \DateTime $fechaAlta
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setFechaAlta($fechaAlta)
        {
            $this->fechaAlta = $fechaAlta;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get fechaAlta
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getFechaAlta()
        {
            return $this->fechaAlta;
        }

        /**
         * Set fechaNacimiento
         *
         * @param \DateTime $fechaNacimiento
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setFechaNacimiento($fechaNacimiento)
        {
            $this->fechaNacimiento = $fechaNacimiento;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get fechaNacimiento
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getFechaNacimiento()
        {
            return $this->fechaNacimiento;
        }

        /**
         * Set dui
         *
         * @param string $dui
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setDui($dui)
        {
            $this->dui = $dui;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get dui
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDui()
        {
            return $this->dui;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
        /*
         * 1 = SUPER_ADMIN
         * 2 = ADMIN        administrador
         * 3 = SUPERVISOR   supervisor
         * 4 = VENDEDOR     vendedor de tickets
         * 5 = VENDEDOR_INDEPENDIENTE vendedor de tickets independiente
        */
            if($this->getTipoUsuario() == 'SUPER_ADMIN'){
              return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos(). ' (Super Admin)';
            }
            if($this->getTipoUsuario() == 'ADMIN'){
              return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos(). ' (Admin)';
            }
            if($this->getTipoUsuario() == 'SUPERVISOR'){
              return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos(). ' (Supervisor)';
            }
            if($this->getTipoUsuario() == 'VENDEDOR'){
              return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos(). ' (Vendedor)';
            }
            if($this->getTipoUsuario() == 'VENDEDOR_INDEPENDIENTE'){
              return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos(). ' (Vendedor Independiente)';
            }else{
                return $this->getNombre().' '.$this->getApellidos();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set apellidos
         *
         * @param string $apellidos
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setApellidos($apellidos)
        {
            $this->apellidos = $apellidos;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get apellidos
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getApellidos()
        {
            return $this->apellidos;
        }

        /**
         * Set email
         *
         * @param string $email
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get email
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        /**
         * Set tipoUsuario
         *
         * @param integer $tipoUsuario
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setTipoUsuario($tipoUsuario)
        {
            $this->tipoUsuario = $tipoUsuario;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get tipoUsuario
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getTipoUsuario()
        {
            return $this->tipoUsuario;
        }

        /**
         * Set estado
         *
         * @param string $estado
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setEstado($estado)
        {
            $this->estado = $estado;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get estado
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getEstado()
        {
            return $this->estado;
        }

        /**
         * Set supervisor
         *
         * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $supervisor
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function setSupervisor(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $supervisor = null)
        {
            $this->supervisor = $supervisor;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get supervisor
         *
         * @return \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario 
         */
        public function getSupervisor()
        {
            return $this->supervisor;
        }

        /**
         * Add supervisados
         *
         * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $supervisados
         * @return Usuario
         */
        public function addSupervisado(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $supervisados)
        {
            $this->supervisados[] = $supervisados;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove supervisados
         *
         * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $supervisados
         */
        public function removeSupervisado(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $supervisados)
        {
            $this->supervisados->removeElement($supervisados);
        }

        /**
         * Get supervisados
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getSupervisados()
        {
            return $this->supervisados;
        }
    }
```

This is my twig file

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1 class="page-header">Agregar vendedores a supervisor</h1>
Empleado: {{ supervisor }}
{# <h3 class="page-header">Vendedores asignados</h3> #}
{{ form_start(formulario) }}
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" {# data-parent="#accordion" #} href="#vendedores_asignados">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Vendedores asignados
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="vendedores_asignados" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    {% for supervisados in formulario.asignados %}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{ form_widget(supervisados) }}
                            {{ form_label(supervisados) }}
                            {{ form_errors(supervisados) }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{# <h3 class="page-header">Vendedores</h3> #}
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" {# data-parent="#accordion" #} href="#vendedores_sin_asignar">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Vendedores sin supervisor
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="vendedores_sin_asignar" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    {% for sinSupervisar in formulario.no_asignados %}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{ form_widget(sinSupervisar) }}
                            {{ form_label(sinSupervisar) }}
                            {{ form_errors(sinSupervisar) }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_widget(formulario.guardar)}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ form_widget(formulario.no_guardar)}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
{{ form_end(formulario) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea or suggestion that can help to accomplish this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer for this question:

**Controller.php**

```
public function addSupervisorVendedorAction(Request $peticion, $supervisorId)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $usuario = $em->getRepository('PDBundle:Usuario')->find($supervisorId);

        if (!$usuario) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('El supervisor indicado no está disponible');
        }
        $data = array();
        $formulario = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('asignados', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PDBundle:Usuario', //'property' => 'nombre',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($supervisorId) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.estado = :activo')
                        ->andWhere('u.tipoUsuario LIKE :vendedor')
                        ->andWhere('u.supervisor = :supervisorId')
                        ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('activo','ACTIVO')
                        ->setParameter('vendedor', 'VENDEDOR%')
                        ->setParameter('supervisorId', $supervisorId);
                }
            ))
            ->add('no_asignados', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PDBundle:Usuario', //'property' => 'nombre',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.tipoUsuario like :vendedor')
                        ->andWhere('u.supervisor is NULL')
                        ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('vendedor', 'VENDEDOR%');
                }
            ))
            ->add('guardar', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar','attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary',)))
            ->add('no_guardar', 'submit', array('label' => 'Regresar sin guardar','attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-danger',)))
            ->getForm();

        $formulario->handleRequest($peticion);
        if ($formulario->isValid()) {
            $data = $formulario->getData();

            if ($formulario->get('no_guardar')->isClicked()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("super_admin_main_usuario"));
            }

            if($formulario->get('guardar')->isClicked()) {
                foreach ($usuario->getSupervisados() as $supervisadoPrePersist){
                    $bandera = false;
                    foreach ($data['asignados'] as $vendedorAsignado) {
                        if($supervisadoPrePersist->getId() == $vendedorAsignado->getId()){
                            $bandera = true;
                            $usuario->addSupervisado($vendedorAsignado);
                        }
                    }
                    if(!$bandera){
                        $supervisadoPrePersist->setSupervisor(NULL);
                    }
                }

                foreach ($data['no_asignados'] as $vendedorSinAsignar) {
                    $usuario->addSupervisado($vendedorSinAsignar);
                }
                $em->persist($usuario);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("super_admin_add_supervisor_a_vendedor", array('supervisorId' => $supervisorId)));
            }
        }
```

**This is the twig file**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
    <h1 class="page-header">Supervisor</h1>
    <strong>Empleado:</strong> {{ supervisor }}<diV class="spacer-10"></div>
    {{ form_start(formulario) }}
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#vendedores_asignados">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Vendedores asignados
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="vendedores_asignados" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for supervisados in formulario.asignados %}
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                {{ form_widget(supervisados, {'checked': true }) }}
                                {{ form_label(supervisados) }}
                                {{ form_errors(supervisados) }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {# <h3 class="page-header">Vendedores</h3> #}
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#vendedores_sin_asignar">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Vendedores sin supervisor
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="vendedores_sin_asignar" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for sinSupervisar in formulario.no_asignados %}
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                {{ form_widget(sinSupervisar) }}
                                {{ form_label(sinSupervisar) }}
                                {{ form_errors(sinSupervisar) }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{ form_widget(formulario.guardar)}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ form_widget(formulario.no_guardar)}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(formulario) }}
    {% endblock %}
```

The main reason that my first approach didn't work was because the selfreference relation didnt have the nullable=true attribute and when users we created at the very first time some of them dont have a supervisor assigned.